# namespaces and using scope resolution

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have run across something I find odd in C# .NET Core 2.0 and I am wondering what is going on here.

I have a file called FooBar.cs and it looks like this

```
namespace Foo
{
    public class FooClass
    {

    }

    namespace Bar
    {
        enum BarEnums
        {
             Bar1
            ,Bar2
            ,Bar3
        }
    }
}
```

And I have a simple program that looks like this

```
using System;

using Foo;

namespace Using
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            FooClass fooClass = new FooClass();

            Console.WriteLine(Bar.BarEnums.Bar1);
        }
    }
}
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Program.cs(16,22): error CS0103: The name 'Bar' does not exist in the current context
```

I am confused as to why the using statement exposes the class within the name space but it does not expose the namespace also found at the same level? If I put in `using Foo.Bar` it still gives the same error.. so the using statement can see the namespace but it does not help it find the references below.

Now if I put in `Foo.Bar.BarEnums.Bar1` it will work just fine.. But why do I not have to put in `Foo.FooClass` following the same nomenclature as with the reference to the enums? Is this just a difference between accessing enums vs classes from within a namespace?

Answer (score 3):

That happens because `using Foo` only imports the types contained in the given namespace, but it does not specifically import the nested namespaces. So that´s why when you reference your `enum` you have to do it with the full namespace reference.

This is a C# language specification.

Here is an explanation from a guy from the C# team:

> In C#, when you specify a “using” clause, such as
>
> using System.Text;
>
> the compiler only imports the types in System.Text into the global
>   namespace – it doesn’t do the same with any namespaces inside of
>   System.Text. So, while that using allows me to write:
>
> StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
>
> it does not allow me to write:
>
> RegularExpressions.Regex r = new RegularExpressions.Regex();
>
> Why?
>
> Well, an early version of the C# compiler had that behavior, but we
>   found that it had a few issues:
>
> First, it made the code harder to follow. In the above example,
>   RegularExpressions.Regex() could be a global name, or a name based on
>   any of my using clauses. Having to look at the top of your code to
>   figure out what a name is is something we’d like to avoid.
>
> The second problem had to do with collisions between namespace names,
>   which occurred much more often with this behavior. If there was
>   another namespace with a RegularExpressions namespace inside of it,
>   the user wouldn’t be able to have a “using” statement for both – even
>   if they didn’t actually care about that namespace.
>
> We therefore decided to change the behavior.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2004/03/07/why-dont-namespace-using-directives-import-nested-namespaces/

And here is the C# spec: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/namespaces