# Why does c# not let me simplify this namespace reference?

Tags: c#, namespaces

I have a project with a namespace and class defined like

```
namespace My.Company.Project.Models
{
   class Item
   {...}
}
```

and then in another project I try to use this class:

```
using My.Company.Project;
...
var obj = new Models.Item
```

but the compiler says that the "Using directive is unnecessary" and I get an error

> CS0246 - The type or namespace name 'Models' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

If my usage instead is

```
using My.Company;
...
var obj = new Project.Models.Item
```

it works fine. Why can I use `My.Company` but not `My.Company.Project` in my using statement and how can I qualify this so that I don't need such verbose namespace naming of classes?

Comment: same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47298277/namespaces-and-using-scope-resolution ?

Comment: Where the `var obj = new Project.Models.Item` is located? Is there any chance it is in `My.Company` or `My.Company.{xxxx}` namespace?

Comment: @MarcGravell: That does seem quite similar, thanks. Following the links in that post led me to the solution of nested namespaces: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6297323/349974

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and then in another project I try to use this class:

And highly likely that this project is in `My.Company` namespace too. And according to the [specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/namespaces#142-compilation-units)

- The following

  ```cs
  namespace N1.N2
  {
      // ...
  }
  ```

  is equivalent to

  ```cs
  namespace N1
  {
      namespace N2
      {
          // ...
      }
  }
  ```
- And (I guess):

  > Namespaces are open-ended, and two namespace declarations with the same fully qualified name (§7.8.2) contribute to the same declaration space (§7.3).

So both parts will be in the same `My.Company` declaration space making `using My.Company;` actually obsolete (i.e. you should be able to do `var obj = new Project.Models.Item();` even without using, at least this is the way I was able to repro the behavior).

If needed you can define [an alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive#using-alias) for the `Models`:

```
using Models = My.Company.Project.Models;

//...
var obj = new Models.Item();
```

Answer (score 0):

After further research (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47298277/namespaces-and-using-scope-resolution), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30164689/using-nested-namespaces), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297279/nested-namespaces)) I learned this this behavior is [by design](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6297795/349974):

> The key point is that it says "exactly one type", not "exactly one
> type or namespace". We deliberately disallow you "slicing" a namespace
> name like this when you are outside of that namespace because it is
> potentially confusing. As others have said, if you want to do that
> sort of thing, fully qualify it once in a using-alias directive and
> then use the alias.

I my case, I can accomplish the desired syntax with the alias `using Models = My.Company.Project.Models`